# Why are there Multiple Electronics SE sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51

There seem to be three SE sites related to electronics:

- [Chiphacker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), a rather active SE 1.0 site which I think is about to be upgraded to SE 2.0
- [Electronics Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), which I only just found out, linked from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/is-there-a-stackoverflow-for-hardware-designers), it looks to be pretty dead
- [Electronics and Robotics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electronics-and-robotics), a new SE 2.0 proposal currently on Area51 in the Commitment phase

To me, it looks like they all have the same scope. Shouldn't just one electronics site be enough?

**EDIT**: For reference, there's now a question on Chiphacker itself about this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/what-about-electronics-and-robotics-in-area51

Comment: @Kip Note sure, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6331/what-is-stackexhange-to-be-used-now-in-the-area51-era says to go here for SE 2.0 stuff. Anyway it's there now too as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6356/multiple-electronics-se-sites

Comment: @Wim, For future reference, please don't cross post. Specifically, since we don't have control over which SE 1.0 sites exist, duplicate, ect, this question (as it relates to SE 2.0) belongs here.

Comment: "Electronics Exchange"?  _Have we learned nothing from Experts-Exchange?_

Comment: [Signal Processing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-processing) covers this area also.

Comment: @Popular Demand: ElectronicSexChange does sound more interesting than ExpertSexChange though

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/what-about-electronics-and-robotics-in-area51/3967#3967) from a Chiphacker admin, they're moving to another platform.  Whether proposals should be closed as duplicates of Sharpado or OSQA sites is another matter, but, according to SE, they're no longer a duplicate.

I posted [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416) on Electronics Exchange on the 5th, 5 days ago, and it has less than 10 veiws at the time of this writing.  Other questions were legitimately asked on August 3rd and 4th, but none have more than 10 views, and the other 7 questions this month are all Community user bumps.  It is clear that EE is in its last few months.

This is why the Electronics and Robotics community was created.  The first comment on the site (by the creator) says:

> This would be the SE 2.0 version of
>   Chiphacker – Jared Harley Jun 3 at
>   2:55

The goal *is* to have only one electronics/physical computing/embedded systems site.

Comment: EE does indeed seem to be dying out, most users have moved to Chiphacker some time ago. I agree that a non-SE hosted Chiphacker would not be a duplicate per se, but I would find it very strange to try and compete with them -- the overall idea behind SE was to make the internet a better place and get way from the duplication...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the Electronics and Robotics proposal should be re-named to just "Robotics", for the following reasons:

1. Chiphacker is already an active SE.
2. There is currently no Robotics SE.
3. Since the topic robotics includes Mechanics, Electronics and software, the name "Electronics and Robotics" makes as much sense as "Software and Robotics" or "Mechanics and Robotics".

Hugo

Comment: There's lots of robotics people already on ChipHacker. If there is a real need for a separate robotics SE then fine, but I fear the overlap with CH might become a bit too large.

Comment: It won't. Robotics is a *huge* field, covering not just Electronics, but also Software, Mechanics, Mathematics, Manufacturing, AI and Philosophy. Imagine that Stack Overflow had been called "Software and Robotics". Doesn't make sense does it?